# Dijkstra shortest path algorithm doesn't work correctly with large numbers C++

Tags: c++, priority-queue, shortest-path, dijkstra

I'm trying to make Dijkstra shortest path algorithm work with large numbers for a weighted, undirected graph with parallel edges using a priority queue. I have memory (64Mb) and time (1 sec) limits. The problem is it gives the wrong answer when the graph is huge. I know that because there is a platform (made by my university) where a program is testing and it shows the wrong answer on the 13th test taking up more memory than in previous tests.

```
typedef unsigned long int vertex_t;
typedef unsigned long int weight_t;

const weight_t max_weight = 1000000000;

struct neighbor 
{
    vertex_t target;
    weight_t weight;
    neighbor(vertex_t arg_target, weight_t arg_weight)
        : target(arg_target), weight(arg_weight) { }
};

typedef pair<weight_t, vertex_t> weight_vertex_pair_t;

void ShortestPath(vertex_t source, vertex_t target, 
                    const vector<vector<neighbor> > &adjacency,
                    vector<weight_t> &min_distance, vector<vertex_t> &previous)
{
    int n = adjacency.size();
    min_distance.clear();
    min_distance.resize(n, max_weight);
    min_distance[source] = 0;
    previous.clear();
    previous.resize(n, -1);
    priority_queue<weight_vertex_pair_t, vector<weight_vertex_pair_t>,
            greater<weight_vertex_pair_t> > vertex_queue;
    vertex_queue.push(make_pair(min_distance[source], source));

    while (!vertex_queue.empty()) 
    {
        weight_t dist = vertex_queue.top().first;
        vertex_t u = vertex_queue.top().second;
        if (u == target)
        {
            cout << min_distance[u];
            break;
        }
        vertex_queue.pop();

        if (dist > min_distance[u])
            continue;

        const vector<neighbor> &neighbors = adjacency[u];
        for (vector<neighbor>::const_iterator neighbor_iter = neighbors.begin();
             neighbor_iter != neighbors.end();
             neighbor_iter++)
        {
            vertex_t v = neighbor_iter->target;
            weight_t weight = neighbor_iter->weight;
            weight_t u_distance = dist + weight;
            if (u_distance < min_distance[v]) 
            {
                min_distance[v] = u_distance;
                previous[v] = u;
                vertex_queue.push(make_pair(min_distance[v], v));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have this while loop in main to fill the graph. Vertices count starts from 1 that's why I'm subtracting one.

```
while (y < edges)
{
     cin >> a >> b >> c; // vertex, neighbor, weight
     adjacency[a-1].push_back(neighbor(b-1, c));
     adjacency[b-1].push_back(neighbor(a-1, c));
     y += 1;
}
```

Comment: is this 32 or 64 bit code?  What is the size of your unsigned long?  I ask because your weight is so big that it barely fits in a 32-bit value.  Turn on compiler warnings as well to be sure.

Comment: Basically, if a 32-bit value and doing any sort of multiplication or division, or even large adds at that size, you could be overflowing your values.

Comment: What is the limit of graph size and costs?

Comment: Yeah, if you have a lot of edges with big numbers like that, you're going to overflow the range of a 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this an answer as it seems to have consensus:

Your `max_weight` value of 1,000,000,000 is right on the edge of what can fit within a 32-bit signed integer - 2^31 or roughly 2,000,000,000.  If you do any sort of multiplication or divison with numbers this bug, you will overflow 32-bit variables.  Even adds and subtracts at that scale can cause overflow.

So, you can:

- Scale down all your sizes by quite a bit, probably below 2^15 if you are doing big multiplies or divisions.
- Use 64-bit math to ensure that your precision is preserved.  For 64-bit, the compiler may handle this for you, but it will run slower.
- If you don't need perfect precision for comparisons, you can use floating point as it can span much greater ranges at the cost of precision.

And in general:
Double check with `sizeof()` just to be sure of your type sizes and also make sure compiler warnings are enabled as they will catch any static compilation time overflows.